# Haskell package linker error: can't load .so/.DLL for: clang

Tags: haskell, linker, clang, cabal

i guys i have a problem, i want to run a haskell script that imports libClang (`import Clang`), i made a `cabal install libClang` befor and it work

now when i make `runhaskell foo.hs` i get:

```
foo.hs: <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: clang (libclang.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

i know that i have to add the library path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so i add some paths to it because i dont know exactly which i have to use (should i use the lib path to the clang/llvm path or the lib path to the .cabal dir where my LibClang-9.0.0 is?)

so i got:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/home/foo/Downloads/clang+llvm-2.9-i686-linux/lib:/home/foo/.cabal/lib
```

after running runhaskell again, the same problem still extists, what should i do?

Comment: I notice you're having lots and lots of problems getting running with libClang, which isn't surprising -- ffi bindings windows can be slightly tricky. However, I'd suggest that rather than write lots and lots of SO questions, you check out the #haskell irc channel on freenode, where you can find some helpful folks to just walk you though the whole process.

Comment: i dont using windows, i use mint/fedora core

Comment: oh, sorry, mixed this question up. In any case, the same recommendation stands. on the specific question, you need to add to your ld_library_path whatever the directory is where libclang.so is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Arch Linux, at least, clang installs into:

```
/usr/lib/llvm/libclang.a
/usr/lib/llvm/libclang.so
```

so the linker can find this library. You can also add paths to:

```
$ echo $LDFLAGS 
-L/usr/local/lib -L/home/dons/lib

$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/home/dons/lib
```

to help the linker out.